# Minecraft Bukkit Runnable

Tags: java, delay, minecraft, runnable, bukkit

I'm trying to create a minecraft plugin which shoots an arrow 5 times with a 10 tick delay between the shots.

Unfortunately I'm not really experienced with Java, but I'll try my best to understand the answers.

This is my Code:

```java
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){
        player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.SHOOT_ARROW, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        Arrow arrow = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
        Events.removeArrows.put(arrow.getEntityId(), (byte) 1);
    }
}
```

At the moment this code snippet "shoots" 5 Arrows without delay. Now I'm stuck when it comes to adding a delay.

Comment: What is this code, and what is your question?

Comment: how to give Delay to Minecraft Bukkit Plugin?
I Already give 'Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {' But i got error 'Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent'

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What is this code (and why is it incomplete)? You just dumped a half-class into the box.  If you want us to help please respect us by at least formatting your code correctly.

Comment: Then can you please edit your question, include ONLY the part of the code that is relevant, and include the error message?

Comment: You did not include ONLY the part of the code that is relevant, and you did not include the error message.

Comment: ok, already dit it.

Comment: You did not include the error message. This is the THIRD time I'm saying this.

Comment: i edited the quetion too before, please read it.

Comment: I don't see the error message. This is the FOURTH time.

Comment: in the question, i dont ask for any error.. i ask how to add delay between the loop, forget about the error.

Comment: i tried adding Runnable Bukkit, but always error. Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent

Answer (score 1):

```
BukkitScheduler scheduler = getServer().getScheduler();
scheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(yourPlugin, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Execute Arrow Code here
    }
}, 10L);
```

That will execute the code within the `run()`method every 10 ticks, until stopped. To do so, use `this.cancel();` within the Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is with an asynchronous task:

```
//Asynchronous Task
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, () -> {
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){

       player.playSound(player.getLocation(), Sound.SHOOT_ARROW, 1.0f, 1.0f);
       Arrow arrow = player.launchProjectile(Arrow.class);
       Events.removeArrows.put(arrow.getEntityId(), (byte) 1);

        try {
            //pause the task for 10 ticks / half a second
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});
```

This code shoots an arrow then waits 10 ticks and starts over again until the `for` loop is finished.

Usually you shouldn't put a `Thread.sleep()` into your code since it stops the whole server for the time you defined. But since this function is asynchronous we aren't facing this problem.